# Create GitHub action with extra resource for Javascript

Tags: javascript, github, github-actions

I have built a GitHub Action with the Javascript "method".

I have the following `action.yaml` file:

```
name: 'xxx Action'
author: 'xxx'
description: 'Runs `xxx` in your repository.'
branding:
    icon: 'code'
    color: 'purple'
inputs:
    token:
        description: 'Txxxxunt'
        required: true
    groupId:
        description: 'xxxx'
        required: true
runs:
    using: 'node16'
    main: './build/index.js'
```

This is how my `build` folder looks like:

[image]

My index.js must use the `keytar.node` file. Is there a way to include this extra file in the action as well?

I know that GitHub will run the `build/index.js` file but it will fail because it will miss the extra file.

Is there a way to include this file **Only With Javascript** method? I do know I could do the same with Docker method

Comment: You can run a script before you main using [pre](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#runspre) unsure if you can run a .node file tho. Can't you include keytar `const keytar = require('build/Release/keytar');` in you script?

Comment: @Mr.Sven Yes I did: `module.exports = require(__nccwpck_require__.ab + "build/Release/keytar.node")`

My question is whether this `.node` file will be available for the action in runtime

Comment: There is nothing per se that would prevent this from working. Please show how you're using it, how the file is referenced, and what error you get.